# VS: Shortcut to delete word

Tags: visual-studio

I've been looking all over, but can't find the following shortcut:

Does MSVC 2022 have a shortcut, either builtin or via an extensions, to delete the word under the cursor?

I know that Ctrl+Del deletes from the cursor to the end of the word. Ctrl+Backspace deletes from the cursor to the beginning of the word. Ctrl+w selects the current word. But, I can't find deleting the word under the cursor in just one shortcut. I usually do Ctrl+w, followed by backspace.

Another shortcut I wish it had, but which I'm pretty sure it doesn't, is jumping to the vertical and/or horizontal middle of the text window. This is to complement Ctrl+PageUp/PageDown, which jump to the top and bottom of the text window.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XavierPoinas.TextMacrosforVisualStudio201220132015 perhaps? Though you'll need to manually record and assign the shortcut

Comment: @Martheen I have that extension, but that's not the kind of thing I'm looking for. That's designed for longer macros, not for simple shortcuts.